# Removing customise fields during plugin uninstallation

Tags: plugins, customization

I created a plugin that insert a field on the customise theme options. Since I use

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'myregister' );
```

to create the customise, should I use

```
 remove_action( 'customize_register', 'myregister' );
```

when the plugin is deactivated or uninstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) has hooks for that:

You can use [`register_deactivation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) to run a function when the plugin is deactivated.

For uninstall, you have two options. Either [`register_uninstall_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook) or add a file called `uninstall.php` in your plugin folder.

I would not recommend delete plugin options on plugin deactivation though, the user might not know that he is losing his saved data.

Comment: On the other hand, I really hate plugins which leave total mess in database after they are removed... So if plugin stores a lot of data in database, there should be a way to delete it.

Comment: I normally use the uninstall.php method, not the deactivation hook, for deleting data. Sometimes people deactivate plugins during WP upgrades or while debugging.

Comment: Just to be clear. If I use the uninstall.php file, I don't need to do remove_action( 'customize_register', 'myregister' ). Is that right?

Comment: you've got the [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) concept wrong. an `add_action` is triggered when `do_action()` is run. [`remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) will only remove a particular function attached to an action.